# Equality on absolute values in the complex plane.

Tags: complex-analysis

Something I've been wondering.

Suppose $z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4$ are consecutive vertices of a quadrilateral that lie in a circle in the complex plane.

Why does
$$
|z_1-z_3||z_2-z_4|=|z_1-z_2||z_3-z_4|+|z_2-z_3||z_1-z_4|?
$$
It's clear the equality
$$
(z_1-z_3)(z_2-z_4)=(z_1-z_2)(z_3-z_4)+(z_2-z_3)(z_1-z_4)
$$ holds just by elementary algebra. Dividing gives
$$
\frac{(z_1-z_3)(z_2-z_4)}{(z_2-z_3)(z_1-z_4)}=\frac{(z_1-z_2)(z_3-z_4)}{(z_2-z_3)(z_1-z_4)
}+1.
$$
So the desired equality follows if both those quotients are positive. I also observe that the first quotient is just the cross ratio $(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4)$ and the second quotient is just $-(z_1,z_3,z_2,z_4)$. Is there some extra information I'm not seeing that shows that these two quantities are both positive? Thank you.

Comment: Talking about the quotients being positive does not make much sense, unless you can prove they are real numbers.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a restatement of [Ptolemy's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy%27s_theorem).

You can find a complex number [proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy%27s_theorem#Algebraic_proof) on the wiki page above and using that you should be able to complete your proof attempt.